# PHP http basic auth on hosted IIS running .net

Tags: php, asp.net, iis

I'm trying to setup a simple http basic auth login using php on a windows IIS hosted server. I have found hundreds of examples but most refer to unix / apache server using `.htaccess` file as a best practice. The following simple php page works fine in apache, but when I try it on my hosted IIS site, it keeps poping up user/password box. - another [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms955939.aspx#cs_gs_security_cncc) I read states that IIS server will use the credentials to attempt a valid windows user account, not http basic?

php:

```
<?php
// protecting page of unauthorized access

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){ 
    $user = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

    if ($user == 'john' && $pass == 'doe'){
        return;
    }
}

header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Protected zone"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
echo 'Login failed.';
exit;

echo 'yea... you are logged in as: me';
?>
```

UPDATED QUESTION:

I have tried the following and think there might be a solution in here somewhere... since I'm trying to add mild security to a php file in a php folder that is within an ASP.NET website, there might be several conflicts with what I'm trying to achieve. The root of my site has a `web.config` file and some of my folders are application pool pages with their own override `web.config` files... so do I need an override `web.config` file in the php folder to allow for basic auth?

something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">

  <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="45" />
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" />
    <authentication mode="Basic" />
  </system.web>

  <location>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```